# Jquery multidimensional array not working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do a multidimensional array in jquery.

```
var exclude_array = {}; 
$(this).siblings("tr[data-id='" + id + "']").each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    var item_id = $(this).children("td:eq(3)").find("input[name='exclude']").attr("data-item_id");
    exclude_array[id][] = item_id;
});
```

I get the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]`, with `exclude_array[id][]` How do i solve?

Comment: what should your code doing?? or what you expect output to be??

Comment: `exclude_array[id]` should be an array.  So `exclude_array[id][0]`,`exclude_array[id][1]` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're trying to `push` the `item_id` into `exclude_array`. The `array[]` syntax is not used in JavaScript. Instead, you must use `.push()`.

Before that, make sure that the key is defined and that it is an array.

```
if (exclude_array[id] === undefined)
    exclude_array[id] = [];
exclude_array[id].push(item_id);
```